# Concat array fields while pushing into bucket

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following collection of buckets in my mongodb, documents look as follows:

```
{
    "bucketId": "1",
    "items": [
        {
            "alternativeIds": [
                "i-1"
            ],
            "uniqueId": "item-1"
        },
        {
            "alternativeIds": [
                "i-2"
            ],
            "uniqueId": "item-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to insert the following object into the bucket:

```
{
    "bucketId": "1",
    "alternativeId": "it-1",
    "uniqueId": "item-1"
}
```

and the final result should look as follows:

```
{
    "bucketId": "1",
    "items": [
        {
            "alternativeIds": [
                "i-1",
                "it-1"
            ],
            "uniqueId": "item-1"
        },
        {
            "alternativeIds": [
                "i-2"
            ],
            "uniqueId": "item-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice: if there is no "item-1" in the bucket, it must be inserted. Also, if there is no bucket "1" in the collection, it also must be created along with "item-1".

Is there a way to do this at once, with one single command, atomically?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  // find the required bucketId
  "bucketId": "1",
  // locate the items array element
  "items.uniqueId": "item-1"
},
{
  // push new value. Only works for finding
  // first "items.uniqueId": "item-1", but
  // should be OK if uniqueId is truly unique
  "$push": {
    "items.$.alternativeIds": "it-1"
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0nxzBIbOC3S).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but I forgot to mention that I need kind of upsert logic, i.e. if there is no "item-1" in the bucket, it must be inserted. Also, if there is no bucket "1", it also must be created along with "item-1"